# Focus on empty field and display Toast and stays on its current Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, toast

I have one activity and two fragments. In my first fragment, it has a username and password EditText and one submit button. I would like to focus to the field and when it is empty i would like to show a toast and it will stays on LoginFragment where the toast is displayed and doesn't proceed to my MainActivity. But currently when I click the submit button it display the toast but it goes to my MainActivity.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.required_both);
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

Fragment frag = new Fragment();

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_submit:

            if(et_username.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                et_username.requestFocus();
                toast.makeText(context, "Please enter your Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } else if (et_password.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                et_password.requestFocus();
                toast.makeText(context, "Please enter your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(et_username.getText().toString().isEmpty() && et_password.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                toast.makeText(context, "Please enter your Username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(spn_status.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("As Employee")  &&
                    !et_username.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                        && !et_password.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

                    mCallback.onLogin("employee");

                    frag = new HomeEmployeeFragment();

            }else if(spn_status.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("As Employer")  &&
                    !et_username.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                            && !et_password.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

                    mCallback.onLogin("employer");
                    frag = new HomeEmployerFragment();
            }
            break;
    }


    if (frag != null ) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, frag).commit();


    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("LoginFragment", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm still new to android. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you calling `onPause()` in your switch? I thought the idea was to stay in the current screen?

Comment: I thought when using onPause it will stays on the fragment. I'm sorry I don't know when will I use it.

Comment: Android calls onPause when your `Activity` leaves the foreground/isn't on screen. You don't need to call it unless there is behavior there you want to run.

Comment: I see. Thanks. i removed the onPause() but still goes to my MainActivity. What should I do?

Comment: Why you are calling getActivity() when check password field?

Comment: Also, it is not related to your question, but I do not think you really need the `toast` instance. `makeText()` is a static method, so you can just call `Toast.makeText().show()`. for the first two if/elkses, and inline `toast` on the last one.

Comment: My mistake it should also be context and not getActivity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing `frag` as `null` instead of as a new `Fragment`. That way, you won't perform a fragment transaction when the button is pushed. So change:

```
 Fragment frag = new Fragment();
```

to

```
 Fragment frag = null;
```